# Fetching data from url and saving in ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, pdf, fetch

I need to save a pdf/doc document in iPad, when you a click that link. I tried to fetch data from http://meme.hcl.com/sites/default/files/243347_TroubleShootingSqlserver20052008.pdf and am trying to save this pdf in iPad. But I am unable to achieve this. Please help me with it.

```
myGroupsBeanData = [self.groupLinksDocumentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSString *seperator=@"meme.hcl.com/";;
 documentName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",seperator,myGroupsBeanData.linkVal];    
 responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
 webserviceType = GET_PDF_DATA;
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:documentName]];
 [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: When you say that you tried to fetch data, what did you do?  Code?

Comment: myGroupsBeanData = [self.groupLinksDocumentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *seperator=@"http://meme.hcl.com/";
    documentName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",seperator,myGroupsBeanData.linkVal];  
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
 webserviceType = GET_PDF_DATA;    
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:documentName]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];